# Python for the Comparison of excel column elements and print the matched elements in separate column

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have developed the following code and fetched the matched output using a for loop.I need to print these output elements in separate column using python.

excel file name - Sample_data.xlsx
first column - WBS_CODE
second column - PROJECT_CODE

first column and second column are matched and then printed in separate column (column F) using python code. Please find my below code,

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.read_excel("D:\python_work\Sample_data.xlsx", sheet_name = '31Sep')
code = A['WBS_CODE'].tolist()

B = pd.read_excel("D:\python_work\Sample_data.xlsx", sheet_name = '4Dec')
code1 = B['PROJECT_CODE'].tolist()


for x in code1:
    if x in code:
        print(x)
    else:
        print("NA")


output:

NA
NA
NA
APP-ACI-PJ-APAC-EMEA-ENG
NA
NA
```

Comment: So you need to output the results to the same excel file?

Comment: yes exactly Nick. same file in separate column

Comment: I suggest you read this, https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/ particularly onwards from _Writing Values to Cells_. If you can't work it out I'll give it a go as I started learning python yesterday. If you do work it out please post an answer

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am trying to find the solution. Once I get one. I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to export the output and print them in a separate column in excel sheet. Below is the solution,

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook


# Reading the Excel file columns
A = pd.read_excel("D:\python_work\Sample_data.xlsx", sheet_name='4Dec')
code = A['PROJECT_CODE'].tolist()

B = pd.read_excel("D:\python_work\Sample_data.xlsx", sheet_name='31Sep')
code1 = B['WBS_CODE'].tolist()


# Comparison of columns
class test:
    def loop(self):
        result = []
        for x in code1:
            if x in code:
                result.append(x)
            else:
                y = "NA"
                result.append(y)
        print(result)

# Printing data into Excel
        try:
            book = load_workbook('D:\python_work\Aew1.xlsx')
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter('D:\python_work\Aew1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
            writer.book = book
            writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)  # loading all the worksheets in opened Excel
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Column1': result})
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=19)
            writer.save()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File Not found: 'Check the Name or Existence of file specified/'")
        except PermissionError:
            print("File Opened/No-Access: Check whether you have access to file or file is opened")

test().loop()
```

steps that solved:
1. Appended the for loop output to a list 
2. used `openpyxl` library to print the output to a column in excel worksheet.

Thanks guyz for help and support. Have a good day

Comment: That's a different file, not the same file but I'm glad you solved your issue

Comment: Thanks Nick. I will mark it as solution. Let me know if any changes. Have a good day